# mkdir -p for files

Tags: shell, directory, mkdir

`mkdir -p` will create a directory; it will also make parent directories as needed.

Does a similar command exist for files, that will create a file and parent directories as needed?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.. but you could just do mkdir -p /path/to/make && touch /path/to/file... Which would make an empty file in that new directory structure you created all as needed.

Comment: @Kansha combine that with `dirname` and `basename` and we'll only need the single argument; profit! :)

Comment: Aye, good call.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `install` utility will do this, if given the source file `/dev/null`. The `-D` argument says to create all the parent directories:

```
anthony@Zia:~$ install -D /dev/null /tmp/a/b/c
anthony@Zia:~$ ls -l /tmp/a/b/c 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 anthony anthony 0 Jan 30 10:31 /tmp/a/b/c
```

Not sure if that's a bug or not—its behavior with device files isn't mentioned in the manpage. You could also just give it a blank file (newly created with `mktemp`, for example)  as the source.

Comment: This creates **executables** by default.

Answer (score 7):

No, it does not as far as I know. But you can always use `mkdir -p` and `touch` after each other:

```
f="/a/b/c.txt"
mkdir -p -- "${f%/*}" && touch -- "$f"
```

Answer (score 5):

I frequently ran into this kind of situation, so I simply wrote a function in my `.bashrc` file. It looks like this

```
function create() {
    arg=$1
    num_of_dirs=$(grep -o "/" <<< $arg | wc -l)
    make_dirs=$(echo $arg | cut -d / -f1-$num_of_dirs)
    mkdir -p $make_dirs && touch $arg
}
```

So, when I want to create a file inside a path of non-existent directories, I will say

```
create what/is/it  # will create dirs 'what' and 'is', with file 'it' inside 'is'
```

Comment: My man! - thank you, I called it `touchp`, like `mkdir -p`

Answer (score 5):

```
mkdir -p parent/child && touch "$_/file.txt"
```

`$_` is a shell parameter, it expands to last argument of previous command. Example `mkdir test && cd "$_"` will create and `cd` into the directory `test`.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
function mktouch() {
        mkdir -p -- "$(dirname -- "$1")" && touch -- "$1"
}
```

Then reload `bash` then use it like `mktouch your/path/file.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to "fake it".

#### First, some required theory:

Rob Griffiths posted an article in 2007 entitled [*Easily Create Lots of New Folders*](http://www.macworld.com/article/1057853/software-utilities/foldercreate.html) on Macworld.com wherein he discussed using the `xargs` command to read in a list of files to create directories using `mkdir`.

`xargs` is capable of referencing a `placeholder` (`{}`) with the `-I` flag,
which contains the value for each argument passed to `xargs`. Here's the difference between with that flag, and without:

```
$ foo.txt bar.txt | xargs echo
$ => foo.txt bar.txt
$ foo.txt bar.txt | xargs -I {} echo {}
$ => foo.txt
$ => bar.txt
```

`xargs` is also capable of running arbitrary shell commands with the `sh -c` flag:

```
foo.txt bar.txt | xargs sh -c 'echo arbitrary command!'
```

#### Combining the Concepts:

We can combine these concepts with `mkdir -p` instead of `mkdir` and the concept in [@ldx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/24293/ldx)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63099/160508) to produce this:

```
$ cat files.txt | xargs -I {} sh -c 'f="{}" && mkdir -p -- "${f%/*}" && touch -- "$f"'
```

This command basically maps each filename in a line-separated list of files, chops off the file part, creates the directories with `mkdir -p` and then `touch`es the filename in it's respective directory.

#### Here's a breakdown of what happens in the above command:

Say for instance my `files.txt` looks like this:

```
deeply/nested/foo/bar.txt
deeply/nested/baz/fiz.txt
```

- `cat files.txt` produces `deeply/nested/foo/bar.js` `deeply/nested/baz/fiz.txt`
- `deeply/nested/foo/bar.js` `deeply/nested/baz/fiz.txt` is piped to `xargs`
- because we used `-I {}`, `xargs` will translate each argument to it's own command, so we now have:

  - `deeply/nested/foo/bar.txt`
  - `deeply/nested/baz/fiz.txt`
- we then run a shell command that uses the `&&` combinator to group 3 commands that run sequentially - the first command stores the file in an environment variable (that gets re-used on the next file pass) using the placeholder we registered before, so we now have:

  - `f=deeply/nested/foo/bar.txt`
  - `f=deeply/nested/baz/fiz.txt`
- we now have a variable we can pass to `mkdir -p`, but we need to cut out the filename. Simple enough using `'${f%/*}'`:

  - `mkdir -p deeply/nested/foo/`
  - `mkdir -p deeply/nested/baz/`
- and then we just re-reference the `f` variable in its entirety when we `touch`:

  - `touch deeply/nested/foo/bar.txt`
  - `touch deeply/nested/baz/fiz.txt`

Comment: You have all this explaination for what is essentially `cat files.txt | xargs -I {} sh -c 'f="{}" && mkdir -p -- "${f%/*}" && touch -- "$f"'`, which has UUOC, then you subshell into xargs which subshells back into the shell, when a `while read` loop makes more sense

Comment: I'll admit I'm not the most clued up on *nix commands - I don't even know what UUOC is - but I fail to see how this is an awful answer. It is researched, tested and is a working solution to your original question. It's constructive (unlike your rather rude comment). Please, if you feel that I've done something irresponsible here that I should not have, then elaborate further - explain _why_. I don't care much for opinionated debate that has no substance.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest as it keeps it on one line, though setting the variable separately allows you to change it and rerun the command from the history pretty easily.

```
B="./make/this/path" && mkdir -p -- "$B" && touch -- "$B/file.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

## 2022 Answer

```
$  mkdir -p foo/bar/baz.c  &&  rmdir $_  &&  touch $_
```

This solution:

- Is based on tools that you likely already know.
- Requires that you type out the full path only once.
- Does not require creating an intermediate variable.
- Is easy enough to type that you can use it on foreign servers without declaring a function.

`mkdir` creates the full directory path, `rmdir` removes the last portion, and `touch` recreates the last portion as a file. The `$_` pseudo-argument just inserts the last argument of the previous command.

**As a bonus, this method completes `Alt-.` with `$_`, which is the newly-completed file name. Thus, a simple `vim Alt-.` will open the new file.**

Note that filenames with spaces or other non-`A-Za-zא-ת0-9._-` characters should quote the argument shortcuts:

```
$  mkdir -p foo/bar/baz.c  &&  rmdir "$_"  &&  touch "$_"
```

I personally don't take this much care, but you should be aware of the limitation. Thank you to StéphaneChazelas for mentioning it in the comments.

Comment: Since you're using zsh syntax, you might as well do `(){mkdir -p $1:h && touch $1} path/to/file`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thank you, but as I mentioned I like a format that works on boxes that I SSH into. Most *nixy things support Bash syntax but not zsh out of the box. The solution I posted works fine in Bash, it is not a zsh-specific syntax.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I just tested on a few boxen, the syntax in this answer is valid down to at least Bash 4.4 which is the lowest version that I can SSH into for right now.

Comment: In bash, you need quotes around `$_` to prevent split+glob. You can omit them if you know the values of `$_` doesn't contain wildcard characters or characters of `$IFS` (which involves knowing the current value of `$IFS`). Which is why I said it was zsh syntax as zsh doesn't do split+glob upon parameter expansion.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you, of course you are correct. This answer does address the happy case where it's being used by people who typically SSH into nix boxes and create file and are concerned with saving a few keystrokes: sysadmins, who are unlikely to create a file with a space or other non-alphanumperiodunderscoredash character in the filename. I'll add this info to the answer, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
dir=$(dirname "$f")
test -d $dir || mkdir -p "$dir"
```

Comment: The `test` isn't needed; `mkdir -p` doesn't do anything if the dir already exists. Doesn't even return an error.

Comment: And of course, this only creates the directory.