# Force create nonexistent directory via vi or touch?

Tags: vi, touch

There are `-p` option in `mkdir` command to create parent directories as needed

```
wolf@linux:~$ tree
.

0 directories, 0 files
wolf@linux:~$ 
wolf@linux:~$ mkdir dir1/dir2/dir3
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘dir1/dir2/dir3’: No such file or directory
wolf@linux:~$ 
wolf@linux:~$ tree
.

0 directories, 0 files
wolf@linux:~$ 
wolf@linux:~$ mkdir -p dir1/dir2/dir3
wolf@linux:~$ 
wolf@linux:~$ tree 
.
└── dir1
    └── dir2
        └── dir3

3 directories, 0 files
wolf@linux:~$
```

Are there similar features in `vi` or `touch` command?

In this case, I would like to create file `authorized_keys` in nonexistent directory `.ssh` with `vi` or `touch`.

authorized_keys is a file, and not a directory. Hence, `mkdir -p .ssh/authorized_keys` command is not applicable here as authorized_keys will be created as directory, not a file.

```
wolf@linux:~$ ls .ssh
ls: cannot access '.ssh': No such file or directory
wolf@linux:~$
```

Would it be possible to do this without `mkdir .ssh` or `mkdir -p .ssh`?

```
wolf@linux:~$ touch .ssh/authorized_keys
touch: cannot touch '.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory
wolf@linux:~$
```

Comment: Is it possible without `mkdir -p`?

I just want to use vi without mkdir

Comment: That post is itself a duplicate, check the answers to that duplicate target as well.

Comment: The answer on that link was `mkdir -p` which is not my requirement.

Comment: And the vi part is covered elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292733/vim-creating-parent-directories-on-save https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/678/how-do-i-save-a-file-in-a-directory-that-does-not-yet-exist

Comment: Yes, so did you follow the links to the other duplicate and see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63105/70524?

Comment: I've rephrased my question. I don't want `mkdir -p`. But I wanted similar feature in `vi` or `touch` if possible.

Answer (score 2):

To create the `~/.ssh` directory, best is to let `ssh` create it itself, then you know it will be created with the right permissions.

```
ssh localhost
```

(or `:!ssh localhost` from within `vi`)

And accept the key for localhost, will cause `ssh` to create the `.ssh` directory and a `known_hosts` file within.

To make the directory within `vi`, you can also do:

```
:!mkdir -m a=,u=rwx .ssh
```

In `vim`, you can do

```
:!mkdir -pm a=,u=rwx %:h
```

or using its own `mkdir()`:

```
:call mkdir(expand("%:h"),"p",0700)
```

Where `%` is the currently edited file and `:h` like in csh/zsh returns the dirname (head). You could map that to a key or key combination or custom function if you find yourself needing it often though you'd need to find a way to specify the permissions (here `a=,u=rwx` / `0700` so only the owner has read+write+search permission to it).

About mkdir+touch, see: [Zsh: How to create a directory and file inside it with one command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/600130)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. So I guess `-p` option in `mkdir` command or something similar is not available in `vi` or `touch` right?

Comment: @Wolf, `vi` can run arbitrary commands with its `!` `ex` command. `vim` also has its own `mkdir()` function.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't force create a directory with `vi` or `touch`.

You still need to create it with `mkdir`, or use it with `-p` flag.

```
-p, --parents     no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

If there is a way to do that with `vi` or `touch`, feel free to update the answer.